# How to make this query work when nothing is not being printed?

Tags: sql, inner-join, subquery

I have 3 database file given image contains its schema
I want to fetch all the actor name who worked on the movie "Sholay"

[image: Database Schema]

I tried below query

```sql
SELECT NAME
FROM Person
WHERE Person.PID IN (SELECT PID 
                     FROM M_Cast
                     WHERE MID IN(SELECT MID FROM Movie WHERE TITLE="Sholay"))
```

But nothing is being shown in the output screen and I can't find some other way to get this solved.

Comment: We need more info for troubleshooting.  Your syntax looks fine other than the use of double quotes.  Depending on the SQL environment (which you did not specify), you might need to use single quotes.  Try just running the innermost query.  Do you get results?  How about the the innermost two queries?  What results do you expect?

Comment: Actually I am running this SQL query in Jupyter Notebook. And 'YES' my two inner queries are working fine I am getting PID of all the actors who acted in "Sholay" Movie. But while trying to print the name of those actors I am getting nothing in as output. And sorry as it's my first time asking question on Stack Overlow so missing the things

Comment: Can you show us the actual data in the tables in your example that you expect to be included in your query?

Comment: I could not understand what you are asking me. What I want as my result is a list of all the actor names who have acted in movie="Sholay". But my inner 2 queries are working well giving me PID of all those actors but when I am trying to print the name of those actors using those PID I am not getting any output.

Comment: @VishalMendekar I don't see an issue with your query, could you share the result of the sub queries and the content of the Person table for the community to help you further ?

Comment: @sash check the answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please can you confirm that in the result you get of this

```
SELECT PID 
FROM M_Cast
WHERE MID IN(SELECT MID FROM Movie WHERE TITLE="Sholay")
```

There is a PID you are looking for with this:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM Person
WHERE Person.PID IN
```

In other words : go to the table Persons and look at the column PID and check if there are the same values as in column PID from table M_Cast that your inner query returns.

You say that your 2 inner query's are working fine and returning some values. Great. But lets say that this numbers are 555, 556, 557 and the values in the column PID in table Person are 001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006.

Also if the PID in table persons is '01'(type varchar) and in table M_Cast is '1'(type varchar) then your query will not return any results as you can see in this small demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=07e0c38f1dee01f460d5d00e3902bb93

At the end try this:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM Person
WHERE trim(Person.PID) IN (SELECT trim(PID )
                     FROM M_Cast
                     WHERE MID IN(SELECT MID FROM Movie WHERE TITLE="Sholay"))
```

Comment: Still the same issue only a heading "Name" is being printed on the screen with no results

Comment: @VishalMendekar you are welcome. Please can you accept this answer as correct? If you do not know how please ask.